# Pegar propriedade de classe C#

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

Galera preciso pegar todas as propriedade de uma classe que seja do tipo classe. Ex:

```
 public class Pessoa{

    public virtual int? Id { get; set; }
    public virtual MinhaClasse1  prop1{ get; set; }
    public virtual MinhaClasse2  prop2{ get; set; }
}
```

Preciso pegar as propriedade `prop1` e `prop2`. Tentei fazer algo do tipo abaixo mas nao funcionou:

```
 var propertiess = pessoa.GetProperties().Where(
     prop => prop.PropertyType.BaseType == typeof(object));
```

Onde pessoa seria uma entidade generica (TEntity). Com a finalidade de montar um `ICriterion` para consultas genéricas com relacionamento entre classes.

```
 foreach (PropertyInfo propriedade in listaPropriedadeClasse) {
            var valorPropriedade = propriedade.GetValue(entity);

            if (!valorPropriedade.IsNull()) {
                criteria.Add(Property.ForName(propriedade.Name).Eq(valorPropriedade));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui uma solução:

```
  var propertiess = entidade.GetProperties().Where(
      prop => prop.PropertyType.IsClass && prop.PropertyType != typeof(string));
```

Comment: Beleza, boa cara!

Answer (score 2):

Uma alternativa para você seria fazer com que suas classes implementem uma interface, por exemplo `IMinhaClasse`.

Ficando assim:

```
public class MinhaClasse1 : IMinhaClasse { }
public class MinhaClasse2 : IMinhaClasse { }
public class MinhaClasse3 { }
```

Observe que a `MinhaClasse3` não implementa a `IMinhaClasse`.

Fiz uma classe Pessoa da seguinte forma

```
public class Pessoa
    {

        public virtual int? Id { get; set; }
        public virtual MinhaClasse1 prop1 { get; set; }
        public virtual MinhaClasse2 prop2 { get; set; }

        public virtual MinhaClasse3 prop3 { get; set; }
        public virtual MinhaClasse2 prop4 { get; set; }

        public virtual MinhaClasse3 prop5 { get; set; }
    }
```

Fazendo a seguinte consulta `Linq` para retornar somente as propriedades que implementem a interface `IMinhaClasse`

```
var properties = type.GetProperties()
                .Where(property => typeof(IMinhaClasse)
                .IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType));
```

Tendo como retorno somente a `prop1`, `prop2` e `prop4`, pois as de mais propriedades são do tipo `MinhaClasse3` que não implementa a interface `IMinhaClasse`

Comment: Tinha pensado nessa alternativa também, mas no meu caso ja resolvi, marquei o comentario que resolveu meu problema como resposta. Vlw!

Comment: porém no seu caso você vai ter problema quando tiver um DateTime na sua classe.

Comment: Fiz um teste aqui e não me retornou os campos do tipo DateTime. Mas vou ficar atento sobre essa questão, se for ter que colocar mais condições na busca, vou adotar a sua sugestão. Vlw!

Answer (score 0):

```
Type objType = typeof(Pessoa);

        Type[] objTypes = objType.Assembly.GetTypes();
        //LEITURA DE TODAS AS CLASSES
        foreach (Type inType in objTypes)
        {
            objType = inType;
            //LEITURA DAS PROPRIEDADES DA CLASSE
            foreach (object obj in objType.GetProperties())
            {
            }
        }
```

Segue abaixo o ajuste que eu fiz:

```
Type[] classes = pClass.Assembly.GetTypes();
        foreach (PropertyInfo propriedades in pClass.GetProperties())
        {
            var verificacao = classes.Where(c => c.Name.Contains(propriedades.PropertyType.Name)).FirstOrDefault();
            if (verificacao != null)
            {
            }
        }
```

Você precisa pegar as propriedades da classe que está dentro da sua classe também ou não? Tipo, pegar as propriedades da classe MinhaClasse1..

Comment: Teria que ser generico, senao preciso comparar classe por classe. E nao sei a classe que pode chegar.

Comment: Certo, você precisa verificar todas as suas classes, e todas as propriedades dela, correto?

Comment: Sim @felipedrt.

Comment: Faça um teste @MarcosVinicius fazendo favor.

Comment: Nesse codigo eu pego todas as classes que esta dentro do projeto, tem como pegar as classe que está dentro soh da classe pessoa nao?

Comment: Mas não era isso que você queria? Se quiser só da classe pessoa, voce faz assim foreach (PropertyInfo propriedades in objType.GetProperties())

Comment: mas eu tenho que eliminar as propriedades nativas (string, int, bool, etc..)do c# tenho q pegar somente as propriedades que são das classe que criei.

Comment: Entendi @MarcosVinicius vou ajustar o código aqui, e ja te mando

Comment: consegui uma solução para o meu problema, descrevi ai nas respostas. Vlw pela ajuda!